# Singleton threadsafe class

Tags: c++, thread-safety, singleton

I have done little work in multi-threaded environments. So, I need to know whether below class's getInstance function is thread-safe or not. Here is singleton class :

```
//Singleton class
class S {
  // intentionally avoided pointer
  static S singleObject;

   // Private constructor   
   s ();
   s (S &);
   s& operator= (const s&);
public:
  // return reference of static object
  s& getInstance ()
  {
    return singleObject;
  }

  /* Normally with static pointer instance, getInstnace look like as
   s& getInstace ()
   {
      // trying to avoid multiple copies of singleObject
      lock_mutex ()

       if (singleObject == null)
          singleObjecct = new S();

      unlock_mutex ();

      return *singleObject;
    }
  */
};

S S::singleObject;
```

In getInstance function (un-commented), static object's reference is returned. Does it requires thread-safe mechanism?

In second getInstance (commented), we create the object if singleObject is null. So, it requires a locking mechanism and needs to be synchronized, right?

Comment: Have a look at http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In getInstance function (un-commented), static object's reference is returned. Does it requires thread-safe mechanism?

As long as you don't access it outside the lifetime of the `main` function, or modify it when other threads might have unsynchronised access, then it's safe to access from any thread.

If you do access before `main` starts or after it ends (e.g. from the constructor or destructor of another static object), then there is a danger that it won't have been initialised, or will already have been destroyed, at that point. That is the motivation for "lazy initialisation" such as your second version.

> In second getInstance (commented), we create the object if singleObject is null. So, it requires a locking mechanism and needs to be synchronized, right?

Yes, that requires a locking mechanism. For compilers that support the C++11 (or similar) threading model, a simpler way to get lazy initialisation like this is to use a function-static variable, which will be initialised in a thread-safe way the first time it comes into scope:

```
S& getInstance ()
{
    static S singleObject;
    return singleObject;
}
```

This will also avoid the memory leak of your version, but introduces a danger that it might be destroyed before other static objects; therefore, it's not safe to access from a static object's destructor.

In general, static objects in C++ are a minefield of such deathtraps (whether or not you try to wrap them up in some kind of singleton anti-pattern) and are best avoided.

Answer (score 2):

In C++11 you can place static instance inside a static function:

```
class S
{
    private:
        S();
        S(S const&);
        S& operator=(S const&);

    public:
        static S& getInstance ()
        {
            static S singleObject;
            return singleObject;
        }
};
```

According to paragraph 6.7.4 of the Standard:

> The zero-initialization (8.5) of all block-scope variables with static
>   storage duration (3.7.1) or thread storage duration (3.7.2) is
>   performed before any other initialization takes place. Constant
>   initialization (3.6.2) of a block-scope entity with static storage
>   duration, if applicable, is performed before its block is first
>   entered. An implementation is permitted to perform early
>   initialization of other block-scope variables with static or thread
>   storage duration under the same conditions that an implementation is
>   permitted to statically initialize a variable with static or thread
>   storage duration in namespace scope (3.6.2). Otherwise such a variable
>   is initialized the first time control passes through its declaration;
>   such a variable is considered initialized upon the completion of its
>   initialization. If the initialization exits by throwing an exception,
>   the initialization is not complete, so it will be tried again the next
>   time control enters the declaration. **If control enters the declaration
>   concurrently while the variable is being initialized, the concurrent
>   execution shall wait for completion of the initialization.** If
>   control re-enters the declaration recursively while the variable is
>   being initialized, the behavior is undefined.

Answer (score 2):

Unless you declare getInstance as static you won't be able to call it. This mistake has propagated almost to all replies. Other than this, I can't add anything better to all the answers.

Answer (score 0):

IIRC this is better for more than this reason. It won't initialize (thread safely) until getInstance is called.

-edit- I remember some reasons now. You can't get access unless that method is called. You can call this in other class constructors and wont need to worry if S has been initialized or no. As in the other class may be constructed first in which case a crash or undefined behavior occurs.

```
//Singleton class
class S {
  // intentionally avoided pointer

   // Private constructor   
   s ();
   s (S &);
   s& operator= (const s&);
public:
  // return reference of static object
  s& getInstance ()
  {
    static S singleObject;
    return singleObject;
  }
};
```